# Edge extension: runtime.sendMessage doesn't receive response

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

I'm writing an Edge extension and struggling with communication between content script and background script.
I'm sending a message from content script to background one:

```
browser.runtime.sendMessage({ name: "get_card_for_website", url: document.URL }, function(response) {
    console.log("Got card for the website:");
    console.log(response);
    if (response != undefined) {
        if (response.card) {
            g_card = response.card;
            callback(response.card);
        }
    }
});
```

Listener in background script is implemented like this:

```
browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.name == 'get_card_for_website') {
        get_card_for_website(request.url)
            .done(function(element) {
                if (element.cards && element.cards.length != 0) {
                    if (element.cards.length == 1) {
                        sendResponse({'card': element.cards[0]});
                    }
                    else {
                        get_one_card_for_site(element);
                        sendResponse({'card': ""});
                    }
                }
             });
    }
}
```

Debugger shows message is sent to background script and corresponding code is executed up to sendResponse. But back in content script this callback function is never executed. Console shows no errors.
What could I miss?

Update: I've found out that some tabs receive responses and some don't. I don't really understand difference between first and second ones.

Comment: [sendResponse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/onMessage) A function to call, at most once, to send a response to the message. The function takes a single argument, which may be any `JSON-ifiable` object. This argument is passed back to the message sender. Have you tried with a simple object?

Comment: I tried to send nearly empty object. So done function looks like this:
.done(function(element) {
sendResponse({'card': ""});
});
Still callback isn't called

Comment: How does get card for website look like?

Comment: { card: "" } It's just empty. But still it doesn't work

Comment: How does your manifest look like, specifically for content script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured out the reason of the problem. sendResponse() was called in .done() function, which is called asynchronously. And according to manual:

> The **sendResponse** callback is only valid if used synchronously, or if
>   the event handler returns **true** to indicate that it will respond
>   asynchronously.

So I've modified my background script's function this way:

```
if (request.name == 'get_card_for_website') {
    get_card_for_website(request.url)
        .done(function(element) {
            if (element.cards && element.cards.length != 0) {
                if (element.cards.length == 1) {
                    sendResponse({'card': element.cards[0]});
                }
                else {
                    get_one_card_for_site(element);
                    sendResponse({'card': ""});
                }
            }
         });
    return true; // <----- this part I've added
}
```

And now it's working like a charm.